# My matrix doesn’t change when I try to perform scalar multiplication

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

we're supposed to multiply every element in the matrix by a number, in this case "k". not sure what i'm doing wrong but it wont work. HELP! i have edited and added the whole project so far.

```
public class Matrix {

    private int r;//rows
    private int c;//columns
    private int[][] neo; //2D array

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matrix m1 = new Matrix(3,4);
        Matrix m2 = new Matrix(3,4);

        System.out.println(m2);
        try {
            Matrix m3 = m1.multiply(m2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        m2.scaleMult(k);
    }//main

    public Matrix(int row, int column) {
        r = row;
        c = column;
        neo = new int[r][c];
        for(int i = 0; i < neo.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < neo[i].length; j++) {
                neo[i][j] = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 100);
            }//forLoop
        }//forLoop
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(neo));
    }//Matrix
    public Matrix copyMatrix(Matrix m) {
        Matrix copy = new Matrix(m.r, m.c);
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(this.neo[i], 0, copy.neo[i], 0, this.neo[i].length);
        }//forLoop
        return copy;
    }//copyMatrix
    public void scaleMult(int k){

        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)

        this.neo[i][j] * k;

    }//scaleMult
    public boolean equals(Matrix m2) {
        if (this.r != m2.r || this.c != m2.c) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                if (this.neo[i][j] != m2.neo[i][j]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }//equalsMethod
    public Matrix multiply(Matrix m2) throws Exception {
        if (this.c != m2.r) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }//if

        Matrix m3 = new Matrix(this.r, m2.c);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m2.c; j++) {
                m3.neo[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < this.c; k++) {
                    m3.neo[i][j] += this.neo[i][k] * m2.neo[k][j];
                }//forK
            }//forJ
        }//forI
        return m3;
    }//multiplyMethod

}//class
```

Comment: Can you paste the complete code you tried?

Comment: What errors do you face,Matrix class is missing along with multiply method

Comment: the error is " this.neo[i][j] * k;" in the scaleMult method. i really dont know why, do i need the "this.k = k;" statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `scaleMult` method to this and it should work:

```
public void scaleMult(int k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            this.neo[i][j] *= k;
            // you forgot to assign the value, basically we multiply neo[i][j] by k and make neo[i][j] receive that value
            // making this.neo[i][j] = this.neo[i][j] *k; would work as well
        }
    }
}//scaleMult
```

Also, based on the example you provided on your `main` method, your code will launch an exception on the `multiply` method, because as you specified, you can only multiply two matrixes if one's columns amount is equal to the other's row amount. Other than that, I would advise on creating a new class just for your main method.

Comment: you sir are my hero :) i'd be staying up all nigh cuz this is due tomorrow. thank you again

Comment: Why would you need to separate class for the main method? The method is static, so it does not need a `Matrix` to work. I am not saying that having the main method in the same class is good idea, but in a class, which is fairly self-contained I can accept that this is a good way for debugging the class. I have seen this many times.

Comment: I tried using as it is in my IDE and it didn't work at all (project just started and closed immediately). Might be related to how I've set everything up though.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is multiply a matrix by a number, then here is a very simple example.

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    int[][] a = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int[][] b=new int[2][3];
    int i,j,k=2;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            b[i][j]=a[i][j]*k;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            System.out.println(b[i][j]);
 }
```

There must be some array variable on left which should be assigned the multiplied value.

Do this helped? If not, please post your complete code.